# C# overload is puzzled

Tags: c#, overloading, implicit

```
public static class Program
{
    static void ImplicitTest(object value) => Console.WriteLine("Implicit to object: " + value)

    static void ImplicitTest(PlatformID id) => Console.WriteLine("Implicit to enum: " + id);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ImplicitTest(DayOfWeek.Sunday);
        ImplicitTest((int)DayOfWeek.Sunday);

        var value = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        ImplicitTest(value);
        ImplicitTest((int)value);
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Implicit to object: Sunday
Implicit to enum: Win32S
Implicit to object: Sunday
Implicit to object: 0
```

Why the output of line 2 is "**Implicit to enum: Win32S**" rather than "**Implicit to object: 0**"?

Comment: I'm more suprised by the last line. It should infer the `PlatformID` overload, too, imho. `PlatformID` is the "smaller" matching/convertable-to type.

Comment: Surprisingly [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) also says that ` If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).`

Comment: @JenishRabadiya This is specific to the value of `Sunday`, which is zero, and the fact that it is a compile-time constant. Jon explains this very well in his answer to the question of which this is a duplicate.

Comment: Note that if you put `DayOfWeek.Monday`, it calls the `object` overload instead, which seems to indicate that it is because the compiler is seeing the constant zero value and allowing that to match an enum.

Comment: Only constant zero is autoconverted to enums, no other value. An int *variable* is thus not guaranteed to be 0 even if it happens to be that at runtime, but the choice of which overload to call is done at compile time. So yes, it is surprising if you don't know the spec around this.